# Implementing a menu's "selected" links in Yii

Tags: yii, selecteditem

I have two templates to integrate into yii - my front end website and my CMS.

1. My front end website has top menu that is generated by CMS (database)
2. CMS top menu which is static menu by me. ("Manage pages", "Manage users", "Manage products") although this menu is static I still want to assign a selected class to the appropriate top menu item.

Eg: If I'm managing some pages on the site the "Mange pages" link should be highlighted and selected. How would I go about this? Something I need to code myself or is there a existing function in yii that i need to refer to?

Thanks in advance
Yii newbie

Comment: Did you see Yii's CMenu widget? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu

Answer (score 1):

What I do is have multiple "menu" functions in my Controller (`AdminController extends Controller`) class. Each one builds the array the [CMenu](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu) needs, and I set the active one based on what I passed in to the function. For instance:

```
protected function getAdminMenu($activeTitle) {
  return array(
    array('label'=>'Manage pages', 'url'=>array('/user/purchase'),'active'=>($activeTitle=='Manage pages')?true:false),
    array('label'=>'Manage users', 'url'=>array('/user/index'),'active'=>($activeTitle=='Manage users')?true:false),
  );
}
```

You could do this where it looks like the Controller or Action or URL request and sets the appropriate menu item active as well. This is just an example.

Then in my view, if I want to render the menu with "Manage pages" active, I set my layout's Menu using the function in my Controller class:

```
$this->menu=$this->getAdminMenu('Manage pages');
```

(This assumes that you have `public $menu=array();` declared in your Controller, and  as well. Look at the Blog example to see how this works:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
      'items'=>$this->menu,
    ));
```

)

I hope this gives you some direction!

Comment: `'active'=>($activeTitle=='Manage users')?true:false`, why not just `'active' => $activeTitle == 'Manage users'` :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a css class that changes the background of the object to highlight it.

In your views for the various pages just make the menu item have that particular class.